# A basic question on random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, elementary-set-theory, random-variables

$X$ is a random variable in $(\Omega, F, P)$ . I want to prove the following two statements :

$$\Omega= \cup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i \text{   where  } A_i=\{\omega : X(\omega) \leq i\}$$
$$\emptyset=\cap_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i \text{   where  } A_i=\{\omega : X(\omega) \leq -i\}$$

How to do that ? ($\emptyset$ = null set)

Comment: The first proposition cannot be proved without more information, since there are cases in which it's not true.  The second is meaningless since you haven't told us what $\Phi$ is.

Comment: I changed $n\epsilon N$ to $n\in N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets turn problem 2 into a more "interesting" or "fundamental" problem, which I'll leave to you.

---

Assume for a contradiction that $\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i$ is non-empty.

Then there exists $\omega \in \bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i$. Fix any such $\omega$.

Now observe that for all $i \in \{1,2,3,\cdots\}$ it holds that $\omega \in A_i$.

In other words, for all $i \in \{1,2,3,\cdots\}$ it holds that $X(\omega) \leq -i$. But no real number has this property. Contradiction!

*Conclusion*: $\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i$ is empty.

---

Now, can you prove the last result that was used? Namely, that there is no real number $x$ such that for all $i \in \{1,2,3,\cdots\}$ it holds that $x \leq -i$?

Comment: thanks for your answer. I can give an intuitive argument: if the real number is non-negative then it is trivial. If it is negative (-2.132...) then a number less than that is the next integer (-3). I have not read real analysis. seems that the actual proof is a real analysis proof.

Comment: Yes, that is good intuition. You probably don't need to go any further than that to be honest. To prove the result formally, one has to appeal to the completeness of the real numbers (which is typically taken as an axiom). So it's actually surprisingly technical.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1. show that for any $\omega\in \Omega$ there exists $i$ such that $X(\omega)\leq i$;
2. show that for any $\omega\in \Omega$ there exists $i$ such that $X(\omega)> -i$;